# Virtualbox and Zoom icons appear zoomed in, in fresh Windows 10 installation

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, icons, zoom-meeting

I think I might know the cause of the issue, but don't know the fix. I installed Zoom, and Virtualbox on a fresh Windows 10 install, before I installed the graphics drivers. Once the graphcs drivers were installed, the display changed from 800*600 to 1920*1080.

Since then, the icons for Virtualbox, and Zoom look bloated, and not their original icons.

I have tried the following but it has not helped:

1. Delete icon cache from: C:\Users%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer
2. Delete  icon cache from: C:\Users%username%\AppData\Local folder

[image: Virtualbox icon in Start pinned]
[image: Zoom icon in Start Menu]
[image: Zoom icon in notification area]
[image: Icons appear normal in the icon selector]

I will appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Try spinning up a new, test Windows 10 machine to see if that is the reason. VMware here and continued host driver and Windows updates do not bother the virtual machines.

Comment: @John I did try checking on VM, and the icons appear normal when I installed Zoom

Comment: I use Zoom a lot and on several machines - no issue with Icons. That is (in part) why I suggest you try a test machine.

Comment: The simplest solution might be to uninstall and reinstall the applications.